# What happened to AMSAT-Phase 3E?

Tags: satellites

The web pages related to the unlaunched satellite were last updated in 2007, so I wonder - where is it now? Is it going to be launched someday?

Answer (score 4):

P3E (Phase 3E) was conceived and partially built by AMSAT Germany in the early 2000's. In 2015, Virginia Tech thought they would be able to secure a launch and AMSAT DE was prepared to transfer the space frame to them. This launch never materialized either.

The space launch industry has changed a great deal in the last 5 to 10 years. Finding an HEO (High Earth Orbit) ride for this large of a satellite may never happen short of fully funding the launch. Such a fund raising effort has never been successfully attempted. The P3E concept was great in its time but I doubt that it will ever see space.

Comment: With an actual Phase 4 satellite payload upcoming (Es'hailsat 2), I guess they don't care about the old satellite anymore. Maybe we'll get to see it in a museum?